# How to batch modify files with sed in MacOS

Tags: macos, unix, sed, command-line, macos-catalina

I'm trying to modify a large (4000+) number of files

I've been using sed via terminal to get some results however the scope of the modifications has changed slightly and I'm unsure of how to proceed

What I'm trying to achieve :

- Open *.styl
- Indent entire file by one tab (I've been using **sed -i    '' s/^/'
  '/g** )
- Insert a string (**@media (min-width: xpx)**) at the top
  of the file (this is what's giving me issues)
- Move to next file

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Have been scouring the internet for a solution but I'm not the greatest when it comes to using the command line so I'm unsure of how to modify certain commands and I'm unfamiliar with the syntax & usage

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
    for file in ./*.styl; do
        sed -e $'1i\\\n@media (min-width: xpx)\n' -e $'s/^/\t/' "$file" > "$file.tmp" &&
        mv "$file.tmp" "$file"
    done
```

Some helpful user over at r/unix helped me sort this one out.